# How to get current url from webview?

Tags: java, android, url, webview

I am developing an android application in which I am using `Webview` object. I am sending an `url` and couple parameters to `Webview` object. Please check below line.

```
String url = "www.myurl.com";
webView.postUrl(url,EncodingUtils.getBytes(postStr, "utf-8"));
```

For now, I can see my `url` in `webview`. This url has couple submission functionality, At the end of scenario, it sends me to success url. But I am not getting that `url` pro-grammatically. I have used To get that url using below function of webview.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
}
```

It's working for earlier `urls` but its not getting for final `url`.

How to do that?

Comment: how about `String webUrl = webView.getUrl();`

Answer (score 2):

@SagarP is correct. `webView.getUrl()` will return the URL according to the [WebView Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl())

Answer (score 0):

`webView.loadUrl("THE URL");`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The answer you provided may be correct. But it's always better to provide description of the code you posted. Also please provide any documentation (a link) if available. Please go through : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer